# Show entries for a certain date with a custom date field using Super Search

Tags: custom-fields, date, solspace, supersearch

I am looking to display entries based on a custom date field using Solspace Super Search.

I want to be able to use a date picker to select a date in a search form and then use Super Search to only show entries based on that particular date, no entries before or after it.

The dates are stored in EE using a native EE date field.

My field name is next_box

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your field name to:
next_box-exact

Then. SuperSearch will return only those entries that match that date.

Comment: Do i use a search value like yyyy/mm/dd or does it have to be a time stamp?

Comment: The EE date field stores as unix time. i. e. 2013-08-19 is stored as 1376884800

Comment: Thanks, so if i was using the jQuery UI date picker would i need to convert the value before searching?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Another option would be to not use the date field and store the data as text.

Comment: Good idea! Maybe a work around.